# Programmatically find outer contour of point cloud prescribed by non-linear transformations

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

Suppose we have an analytical non-linear function $\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ as:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{q}_{(\alpha)}=0
\end{equation}
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $ and $\mathbf{q}\in \mathbb{R}^{n} $. Each term of $\alpha$ is bound to take any value between $[-1,1]$. For simplicitly limit the treatment to $m=3$, $n=2$ for the example. How can we programmatically determine the contour of the domain that $\mathbf{q}$ creates?
I have made an illustration of the problem here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ngsyatkz1f. For a linear transformation the contours are part of a polygon in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I have found a way to determine their verteces. How to generalize the solution to non-linear functions?

**My attempt**

The previous equations allows to calculate the $[n\times m]$ Jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}$. To determine the outer contour in a certain direction $\epsilon_i$ we wish to move along a certain direction $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ that makes $d\mathbf{q}^T \epsilon_i>0$. We can do that by using an auxiliary scalar variable $s$ and  selecting:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dq}{ds} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial a} v_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
da = ds v_i
\end{equation}
Where $v_i$ has components:
$$  v_{ij}  =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{sign}\{ \epsilon_i^T \frac{\partial q}{\partial \alpha} \epsilon_j  \}  & |\alpha_j| < 1 \\
 0 & |\alpha_j| \geq 1 \\ 
\end{array} \right .\ $$
The solution can be initialized anywhere in the usable domain of $\alpha$. In the non-linear case it is an ODE, otherwise it can be resolved in one-go.
Of course there would be more choices for $v_i$ possible, but irrespectively of the choice chosen the solution will converge to the verteces describing $\text{max}\{\mathbf{q}^T\epsilon_i\}$ with the bounds of $\alpha$ prescribed above.

The issue I have with above approach is that it convergeces to $\text{max}\{\mathbf{q}^T\epsilon_i\}$, but the latter doesn't necessarily represent the contour shape of $\mathbf{q}$ but only the outer convex verteces. If the contour is in part concave as in below image, how can we determine it?

An improved version of this that resolves above issues would be to impose the bigger constraint that
$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial a} v_i =  \epsilon_i$$
This condition constraints the choice of $v_i$ to lead to only movements of the $d\mathbf{q}$ in the (positive) direction $\epsilon_i$.
The previous system can't be resolved classically because $\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}$ is not a square matrix.  As a result it will also have more than one solution given a set of degrees of freedom $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, as:
\begin{equation}
v_i = \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)^{+}\epsilon_i + \left(I-\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)^{+}\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)w
\end{equation}
where the Moore-Pseudo inverse is used.
Now, the problem starts if we are close to the conditions $|\alpha_j|=1$. There still may be some values of $w$ that allows to fulfill those conditions by still allowing for $dq$ to grow in the direction of $\epsilon_i$.  Those conditions be imposed as a projection matrix in the solution for $v_i$. Thinking something of the form:
\begin{equation}
v_i' = P v_i
\end{equation}
where $P_{jj}=0$ if $\text{sign}\{v_{ij}\alpha_j\}\geq 0$ and $|\alpha_j|=1$. How can I determine the subspace of $w$ fulfilling those criteria?

To sum up, I am looking into a way of determining a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for $w$ for which:
\begin{equation}
\text{sign}\left\{\alpha_j e_j^T\left[\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)^{+}\epsilon_i + \left(I-\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)^{+}\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)w \right]\right\} < 0
\end{equation}
for all $j$ for which $|\alpha_j|=1$
Up to when solution does not exist anymore.
By imposing the equality for all $j$, I found (one) solution
\begin{equation}
w = -\left(\sum_j \epsilon_j\epsilon_j^T  \left(I-\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)^{+}\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)\right)^{+} \sum_j  \epsilon_j\epsilon_j^T \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\right)^{+} \epsilon_i
\end{equation}
which seems to work in the limiting case in which all $j$ are bound because $\sum_j \epsilon_j\epsilon_j^T = I$ and $v_i=0$.
Since this is a little complicated, and not sure if fully correct, if other implementation ideas on how to do this exist it would be also very helpful.

[image: Example of a non-convex contour shape resulting from a non-linear equation]